# Ruby 99 bottles of beer on the wall, DRY principle

Tags: ruby, string, variables, methods, dry

**I was wondering if there is a way for me to avoid writing .to_s method on bottles_of_beer variable? (DRY principle)**

```
bottles_of_beer = 99

while bottles_of_beer != 1

beer_left = bottles_of_beer - 1

bottles_of_beer = beer_left

puts bottles_of_beer.to_s + ' bottles of beer on the wall ' + bottles_of_beer.to_s + ' bottles of beer.'

puts 'Take one down and pass it around, ' + beer_left.to_s + ' of beer on the wall.'

end

if bottles_of_beer == 1

puts bottles_of_beer.to_s + ' bottle of beer on the wall, ' + bottles_of_beer.to_s + ' bottle of beer.'

puts 'Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.'
end

puts 'No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.'

puts 'Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.'
```

**I was wondering if there is a way for me to avoid writing .to_s method on bottles_of_beer variable?**

Comment: Please use [appropriate formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for your source code.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would use [*string interpolation*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) for this, which will use `to_s` automatically, if necessary:

```rb
puts "#{bottles_of_beer} bottles of beer on the wall #{bottles_of_beer} bottles of beer."
```

By the way, your code would normally be implemented more like this:

```rb
puts 99.downto(2).map { |number_of_bottles|
  "#{number_of_bottles} bottles of beer on the wall #{number_of_bottles} bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, #{number_of_bottles - 1} of beer on the wall."
}

puts 'Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.'
puts 'No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.'
puts 'Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.'
```

Comment: Donald Knuth proved that the song has a complexity of `O(log N)` in his article ["The Complexity of Songs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complexity_of_Songs). (You are missing " bottles" in one place, though that should be "bottle" when `number_of_bottles #=> 2`. Also, shouldn't you write, say, "seven", rather than "7", for number_of_bottles < 10`?)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Jorg idea with interpolation but more of a functional approach, just for fun:

```
def bottles_song(n)
  if n.zero?
    puts "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer!\nGo to the store and buy some more, #{n} bottles of beer on the wall.\n"
    return
  end

  puts "#{n} #{ n != 1 ? 'bottles' : 'bottle'  } of beer on the wall, #{n} #{ n != 1 ? 'bottles' : 'bottle' } of beer.\nTake one down, pass it around, #{n != 1 ? (n-1) : 'no more'} #{ n != 1 ? 'bottles' : 'bottle' } of beer on the wall!\n"

  bottles_song(n-1)
end
```

Improved readability but it's taking other methods, not really an improvement :)

```
def bottles_song(n)
  if n.zero?
    puts "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer!\nGo to the store and buy some more, #{n} bottles of beer on the wall.\n"
    return
  end

  puts_bottles(n)
  bottles_song(n-1)
end

def puts_bottles(n)
  puts "#{n} #{ pluralize_bottle(n)  } of beer on the wall, #{n} #{ pluralize_bottle(n) } of beer.\nTake one down, pass it around, #{n != 1 ? (n-1) : 'no more'} #{ pluralize_bottle(n-1) } of beer on the wall!\n"
end

def pluralize_bottle(n)
  return 'bottles' if n != 1
  'bottle'
end
```